# MS Access SQL Transform Aggregate Manipluation of Values for Pivot

Tags: sql, ms-access, pivot

I have been reading and diving into depths of SQL and I think I am successfully confused over this now. An example table I have is:

```
Date       Quantity       Type       Date_Entered
01/02/15   23             Orange     10/01/15
01/02/15   10             Red        10/01/15
01/02/15   18             Yellow     10/01/15
02/02/15   15             Yellow     10/01/15
02/02/15   19             Red        10/01/15
.          .              .          .
.          .              .          .
```

Date is the calendar date of projected sales, Quantity is the number of sales, Type is the type of product (this may vary with the number of types), Date_Entered is the date that the data was put into the table and gives the forecast for the other columns. For each Date_Entered, there is the range of dates (say the whole of 2015). For each Date, there is every Type available.

Now, I have been trying to pivot the table with an SQL query in MS Access (because I'm using this with a macro in Excel) to get a table like the following:

```
Date        Orange    Red    Yellow
01/02/15    3         2      5
02/02/15    0         -2     -1
03/02/15    8         -1     2
.           .         .      .
.           .         .      .
```

Where the values are the difference between the Quantity sold for a particular Date from one Date_Entered to another (e.g. change in projected sales over a week, month, quarter).

So far, I have evolved the following:

```
TRANSFORM IIF(FIRST([Date_Entered]) > LAST([Date_Entered]), 
              FIRST([Quantity]) - LAST([Quantity]),
              LAST([Quantity]) - FIRST([Quantity]))
SELECT [Date] FROM Sales WHERE [Date_Entered] = #2015-01-10# OR #2015-01-20# 
GROUP BY [Date] ORDER BY [Date] PIVOT [Type]"
```

However, FIRST() seems to just bring out zeros and so the above does not give the correct figures. My problem, I think, is working out the aggregate needed for the computation of the values for the table. Hopefully, someone can point me in the right direction.

Thank you for any responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with your WHERE clause. Instead of

```
WHERE [Date_Entered] = #2015-01-10# OR #2015-01-20#
```

try

```
WHERE [Date_Entered] IN( #2015-01-10#, #2015-01-20# )
```

Comment: Just tested this and Wow! Thank you! I have been struggling over this for a while. Why does the date not accept "OR" ? and as a side question could the field names be included in the return query?

Comment: Glad I could help. It is not that the Date does not accept OR, but as it was written, Access interpreted it as a Boolean, ex. #2015-01-20# <> False. If you had included [Date_Entered] in the expression ([Date_Entered] = #2015-01-20#, then you would have gotten the same result as with using the IN clause.

Comment: ah ok - that's making more sense now.